# Epidemic spacial diffusion problem.. how to draw a graph of differential system of second order with partial derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative, python, programming

I'm currently working on how to simulate the diffusion of an epidemic in a population. If we don't consider that the population is moving in space, then the differential system is the following: [Differential System SIS without spacial diffusion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkMMV.png). You'll find the corresponding program below. If we consider that the population (the infected people to be more specific) have an anarchic mobility, the differential system will contain a second order partial derivative in respect to the spacial variable x (the problem is considered in one spacial dimension only) as shows the following picture: [Differential System SIS with spacial diffusion included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERFbB.png). The problem I have is how to implement that second order partial derivative in the program, and how draw the graphs of such a differential system.. (even though there is a spacial variable, the axes remain the same: Population and Time) If you take off the partial derivative, it becomes a simple differential system and the corresponding program I made is the following:

```
from scipy import arange
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N0 = 1000000        #Initial population number
I0 = 100            #Initial infected number
PopuIni = [N0,I0]


b=1/3000000 #infection rate β
g=1/20      #cure rate of Infected people ɣ
d=5/1000    #death rate, not related to the epidemic (common between infected and susceptible)
n=4/1000    #birth rate (vertical infection from parents to progeny is not 
considered here)

def EpidEvol(N,t):
   S,I=N
   derS = n*(S+I) + g*I - d*S - b*S*I
   derI = b*S*I - d*I - g*I
   return [derS,derI]


tmax=157
t=arange(0,tmax,0.1)
N=odeint(EpidEvol,PopuIni,t)
```

Thank you for your attention.. I sincerely hope to receive help from you

**UPDATE 1:**
I found this website which provides a method of solving partial differential equations, but I genuinely don't know how to implement this in my program..
http://hplgit.github.io/prog4comp/doc/pub/p4c-sphinx-Python/._pylight006.html